# Error: Faild to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I'm having issue after installing push plugin of ionic 3.

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push

npm install --save @ionic-native/push@4
```

This is blundder

```
* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
```

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
>   All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

This is a project.properties file

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.3=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.40.0
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-googlemaps/citizen-tbxml-android.gradle
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.12=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+
cordova.system.library.13=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+
cordova.system.library.14=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/citizen-ignorelinterrors.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/citizen-androidtarget.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-support-google-services/citizen-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.15=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.16=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
cordova.gradle.include.5=phonegap-plugin-multidex/citizen-multidex.gradle
cordova.system.library.17=com.android.support:support-v13:27.+
cordova.system.library.18=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.19=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0
```

any help is appreciated.